# Is it possible to provide my AWS credentials in the docker.withRegistry call in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

In my Jenkinsfile, I am trying to push the image that I have built using the docker plugin like follows:

```
docker.withRegistry('https://<my-id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/', 'ecr:us-east-1:awscreds') {
  docker.image('image').push('latest')
}
```

The pipeline fails every time with the message `ERROR: Could not find credentials matching ecr:us-east-1:awscreds` but I do have my AWS key ID and secret key in my Jenkins credentials with the ID "awscreds".
What could be a potential fix for this?

Alternatively, can I provide my credentials directly instead of mentioning the credential ID in the call?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same error message. Make sure the Amazon ECR plugin is installed and up to date and that you reboot jenkins after the installation.

Comment: I wasted 2 days trying all the different AWS configurations for the user. Thank you!